# Ubuntu 20.10: Firefox 82+, Intel HD 500, Vaapi hardware acceleration

Tags: firefox, vaapi

My hardware:

- Intel® Celeron(R) CPU J3455 @ 1.50GHz × 4
- Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 500 (APL 2)
- 7,4 GiB RAM
- Ubuntu 20.10 64-bit, X11

According to several articles on the internet, Firefox v81 / 82 enables vaapi hardware video acceleration on Linux by default.

Looking at `about:config` via Firefox, I can confirm that `media.ffmpeg.vaapi-drm-display.enabled` is set to `true` and `media.ffmpeg.vaapi.enabled` is set to `false`.

I successfully installed the necessary drivers for my gpu via `sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver vainfo`, but Firefox still lacks hardware video acceleration when browsing Youtube (VP9). In addition, I also tried running Firefox via the terminal with the command `MOZ_X11_EGL=1 firefox`, which indeed starts Firefox, but without video acceleration (Youtube is still dropping a lot of frames).

vainfo:

```
MrSmith@MrSmith-NUC6CAYH:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.8 (libva 2.8.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 20.2.0 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

I read that it is necessary to switch to the new `webrender` in order to actually fully activate and use vaapi video acceleration. Is this true? If so, which `about:config` entry do I modify?

What am I missing here? How do I enable vaapi hardware video acceleration via Firefox for my Ubuntu 20.10 X11 installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to enable and verify that 4k/60fps vaapi video hardware acceleration is working via VP9 and X11 on my system.

**Step #1:**

- Ubuntu should already ship with all the necessary Mesa gpu drivers by default (Intel / Radeon)
- In my case, I performed `sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver vainfo` just to be sure
- Usually `sudo apt-get install vainfo` should suffice

**Step #2:**

- Open a terminal and type `vainfo` in order to see what codecs your gpu supports (see my initial question further above)

**Step #3**, launch Firefox and set the following to `true` via `about:config`:

```
 - gfx.webrender.all
 - gfx.webrender.compositor.force-enabled
 - media.ffmpeg.vaapi-drm-display.enabled
 - media.ffmpeg.vaapi.enabled
```

**Step #4**, set the following to `false`, **if** your gpu supports the VP8/VP9 hardware acceleration:

- `media.ffvpx.enabled`

**Step #5:**

- Close Firefox
- Open a terminal and launch Firefox via `MOZ_X11_EGL=1 firefox`

**Step #6:**

- Browse Youtube, for example, and right-click a video -> stats for nerds
- Check viewport / frames for dropped frames (ideally, you should have zero dropped frames)

**Step #7 (optional):**

- Create a shortcut with the env set to `MOZ_X11_EGL=1 firefox`
- See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291569/firefox-82-create-or-edit-shortcut) for more infos

That's pretty much it. Have fun!