# Firefox 82, create or edit shortcut

Tags: firefox, shortcuts

I would like to start and use Firefox with the command `MOZ_X11_EGL=1` without having to type `MOZ_X11_EGL=1 firefox` into the terminal each and every time (I use the command in order to enable vaapi video acceleration on X11).

- How can I edit the existing Firefox shortcut in order to add `MOZ_X11_EGL=1` ?
- How can I create a completely new shortcut with `MOZ_X11_EGL=1` ?

OS: Ubuntu 20.10, using the preinstalled Firefox version that shipped with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit the existing shortcut, copy the desktop file of Firefox from `/usr/share/applications` (`firefox`) to the folder `.local/share/applications` in the home folder. Edit the `Exec=` line.

If more users need to be able to use that launcher, place a copy of the `.desktop` file in a `/usr/local/share/applications` folder. That will override the copy in `/usr/share/applications`. You could edit the original launcher directly, but it might be overwritten by a future update.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. I tried adding "MOZ_X11_EGL=1" to the "exec=" line after performing all the necessary steps beforehand, but Firefox still launches normally, without the env MOZ_X11_EGL=1. Could you tell me how exactly the exec line has to look like in order to launch firefox via MOZ_X11_EGL=1 pls?

Comment: Ok, got it working now. Under "[Desktop Entry]" look for the line "Exec=firefox %u" and replace it with "Exec=env MOZ_X11_EGL=1 firefox %u" (without the quotes ofc). Save the file and launch Firefox normally via the desktop or dash shortcut and voilà - - - Firefox is now using the env MOZ_X11_EGL=1 by default. Thx @vanadium for the help!